# React JS: @material-ui: Invalid Hook Call: On Stackblitz

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, react-hooks

Trying to write an example code on using @material-ui, but the following error always persists, given @material-ui is included in the code.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Hello from './Hello';
import './style.css';
import Box from '@material-ui/core/Box';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';

interface AppProps { }
interface AppState {
  name: string;
}

class App extends Component<AppProps, AppState> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: 'React'
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <Box color="text.primary" clone>
        <Button />
      </Box>
        <Hello name={this.state.name} />
        <p>
          Start editing to see some magic happen :)
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));


https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-oed5mf
```

Comment: what's the error ?

Comment: Hi, I may be missing something but I'm not seeing any error in the stackblitz you provided. Can you post your error message?

Comment: I just happened to fix it. There was  a conflict between  react-dom  and @types/react. Re-installed it and now it works fine. Thanks ibtsam and Jasmonate

Comment: Following was the error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app